# How do I view all duplicates across all rows?

Tags: r

I am running to a problem in my database where they accidentally have duplicate stuff of the same observation where all column/variable values are exactly the same, getting duplicates for that specific observation. How do I view all of these in R so I can investigate?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't give any example data, I will give a general layout.

```
duplicates <- duplicated(df) | duplicated(df, fromLast = TRUE) 
duplicates_set <- subset(df, duplicates == TRUE)
```